# Последовательное изменение фона при наведении на ссылку или div

Tags: jquery, javascript

Привет, ребята!
Мне надо сделать реализацию изменения фона при наведении на див. Навел див окрасился в красный убрал он так красным и остается, еще раз навел он стал синим убрал синим остается ну и так далее.
Немного изменила методы поиска и нашла практически то, что мне надо но только цвета меняются рандомно. Может кто помочь, я только учусь, идея есть на сайте хочу сделать)
Надо что бы можно было цвета задавать в ручную, а не что бы они рандомно менялись
Вот что получается сейчас [Пример например]http://jsfiddle.net/marusia/cL17z15p/[1](http://jsfiddle.net/marusia/cL17z15p/)

Answer (score 1):

Добавь еще одну переменную и проверяй ее значение при наведении. Если равна 1, то ставим зеленый и присваиваем переменной значение 2. Если равна 2, то ставим красный и присваиваем переменной значение 3. И так далее, хоть 64000. Можно просто inc() использовать, кстати, вместо присваивания конкретных чисел.

**Обновление**

Оформите код на jsfiddle, если будет время - напишу пример. Вообще, тут разговор простой: Хочешь учиться - все двери открыты и информации море, учись. Хочешь сразу получить результат - заплати тому, кто учился вместо тебя. А новичкам с 1 вопросом и совсем без ответов даже помогать не хочется, вы, вероятно, просто хотите халявы.

Comment: а можно небольшой пример? куда ету переменную добавить))

Comment: Оформите код на jsfiddle, если будет время - напишу пример. Вообще, тут разговор простой: Хочешь учиться - все двери открыты и информации море, учись. Хочешь сразу получить результат - заплати тому, кто учился вместо тебя. А новичкам с 1 вопросом и совсем без ответов даже помогать не хочется, вы, вероятно, просто хотите халявы.

Comment: Я и учусь. На практике только) А если у вас нет желания помочь, то и не надо, зачем писать про халявы всякие.

Comment: Чтобы учиться надо читать и думать, а не просто спрашивать решения у других.
Вот пример: http://jsfiddle.net/60sdmebu/

Comment: Спасибо.) Я читаю, правда, но еще не дошла до нужного. )))

Comment: @marusia, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).